# How to create an automatic mapping of possible JSON data options to be collected?

Tags: python, json

I've never heard of or found an option for what I'm looking for, but maybe someone knows a way:

To collect the data from a JSON I need to map manually it like this:

```
events = response['events']
for event in events:
    tournament_name = event['tournament']['name']
    tournament_slug = event['tournament']['slug']
    tournament_category_name = event['tournament']['category']['name']
    tournament_category_slug = event['tournament']['category']['slug']
    tournament_category_sport_name = event['tournament']['category']['sport']['name']
    tournament_category_sport_slug = event['tournament']['category']['sport']['slug']
    tournament_category_sport_id = event['tournament']['category']['sport']['id']
```

The complete model is this:

```
{
    "events": [
      {
        "tournament": {
          "name": "Serie A",
          "slug": "serie-a",
          "category": {
            "name": "Italy",
            "slug": "italy",
            "sport": {
              "name": "Football",
              "slug": "football",
              "id": 1
            },
            "id": 31,
            "flag": "italy",
            "alpha2": "IT"
          },
          "uniqueTournament": {
            "name": "Serie A",
            "slug": "serie-a",
            "category": {
              "name": "Italy",
              "slug": "italy",
              "sport": {
                "name": "Football",
                "slug": "football",
                "id": 1
              },
              "id": 31,
              "flag": "italy",
              "alpha2": "IT"
            },
            "userCount": 586563,
            "id": 23,
            "hasEventPlayerStatistics": true
          },
          "priority": 254,
          "id": 33
        },
        "roundInfo": {
          "round": 24
        },
        "customId": "Kdbsfeb",
        "status": {
          "code": 7,
          "description": "2nd half",
          "type": "inprogress"
        },
        "winnerCode": 0,
        "homeTeam": {
          "name": "Bologna",
          "slug": "bologna",
          "shortName": "Bologna",
          "gender": "M",
          "userCount": 39429,
          "nameCode": "BOL",
          "national": false,
          "type": 0,
          "id": 2685,
          "subTeams": [
            
          ],
          "teamColors": {
            "primary": "#003366",
            "secondary": "#cc0000",
            "text": "#cc0000"
          }
        },
        "awayTeam": {
          "name": "Empoli",
          "slug": "empoli",
          "shortName": "Empoli",
          "gender": "M",
          "userCount": 31469,
          "nameCode": "EMP",
          "national": false,
          "type": 0,
          "id": 2705,
          "subTeams": [
            
          ],
          "teamColors": {
            "primary": "#0d5696",
            "secondary": "#ffffff",
            "text": "#ffffff"
          }
        },
        "homeScore": {
          "current": 0,
          "display": 0,
          "period1": 0
        },
        "awayScore": {
          "current": 0,
          "display": 0,
          "period1": 0
        },
        "coverage": 1,
        "time": {
          "initial": 2700,
          "max": 5400,
          "extra": 540,
          "currentPeriodStartTimestamp": 1644159735
        },
        "changes": {
          "changes": [
            "status.code",
            "status.description",
            "time.currentPeriodStart"
          ],
          "changeTimestamp": 1644159743
        },
        "hasGlobalHighlights": false,
        "hasEventPlayerStatistics": true,
        "hasEventPlayerHeatMap": true,
        "id": 9645399,
        "statusTime": {
          "prefix": "",
          "initial": 2700,
          "max": 5400,
          "timestamp": 1644159735,
          "extra": 540
        },
        "startTimestamp": 1644156000,
        "slug": "empoli-bologna",
        "lastPeriod": "period2",
        "finalResultOnly": false
      }
    ]
  }
```

In my example I am collecting `7` values.
But there are `83` possible values to be collected.

In case I want to get all the values options that exist in this `JSON`, is there any way to make this map sequence automatically to print so I can copy it to the code?

Because manually it takes too long to do and it's very tiring.

And the results of texts like `print()` in terminal would be something like:

```
tournament_name = event['tournament']['name']
tournament_slug = event['tournament']['slug']
...
...
...
And so on until delivering the 83 object paths with values to collect...
```

Then I could copy all the prints and paste into my `Python` file to retrieve the values or any other way to make the work easier.

Comment: The "complete model" shown in your question is a string containing data in JSON format. If you want to turn it into the equivalent Python data-structure for further processing, you can do so very simply by calling `json.loads(data_json_string)` and process the results returned from that — which will be a Python dictionary and not require the generation of code that created variables holding the data (which doesn't make sense for lists of items anyway). In other words, your whole approach to this is not a good idea IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements in the events arrays are the same, this code works without errors.

```
def get_prints(recode: dict):
    for key in recode.keys():
        if type(recode[key]) == dict:
            for sub_print in get_prints(recode[key]):
                yield [key] + sub_print
        else:
            yield [key]



class Automater:
    def __init__(self,name: str):
        """
        Params:
            name: name of json
        """
        self.name = name

    def get_print(self,*args):
        """
        Params:
            *args: keys json
        """
        return '_'.join(args) + ' = ' + self.name + ''.join([f"['{arg}']" for arg in args])
```

For example, this code:

```
dicts = {
    'tournament':{
        'name':"any name",
        'slug':'somthing else',
        'sport':{
            'name':'sport',
            'anotherdict':{
                'yes':True
            }
        }
    }
}
list_names = get_prints(dicts)
for name in list_names:
    print(auto.get_print(*name))
```

Gives this output:

```
tournament_name = event['tournament']['name']
tournament_slug = event['tournament']['slug']
tournament_sport_name = event['tournament']['sport']['name']
tournament_sport_anotherdict_yes = event['tournament']['sport']['anotherdict']['yes']
```

Comment: Hi @Halone, thanks for support! And if I want to print all ```83``` the existing options, how would you tell me to do it? Is there any looping option that I can create with ```for in``` for example to deliver all paths?

Comment: Just make a array of all options and in for loop unpacking options. For example
`prints = [['tournament','name'],['tournament','slug']]`
`for print_ in prints:`
`print(auto.get_print(*print_))` 
this print *tournament_name = event['tournament']['name']* and
*tournament_slug = event['tournament']['slug']*

Comment: Oh yes, I understand. Unfortunately this way it would be necessary to type all ```83``` full paths and it would end up having the same difficulty mapping one by one. The idea was to automate without the need to type objects text values one by one!

Comment: Oh, you want to get alls keys from dict? Its also possible.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to explain correctly in the question, I edited the question it to improve understanding!

Comment: Wait a minute. I rewrite the code.

Comment: No problem mate, thanks for support!

Comment: Check now. Its correctly?

Comment: Exactly that my friend, thank you very much!
  Perfect! I can't test it now but from what I've seen this is exactly what I need!

Comment: Hi @Halone , i try use and this error appears ```"auto" is not defined```

Comment: Beacause you didnt define auto
`auto = Automater('event')`