# I want to get the data from a json file

Tags: python, json

I want get the data from the json file. I have this list with the keywords.
I tried this:

```
def get_information(self, path):
   data = get_data() #loads the hole json file
   keywords = get_keywords(path)
```

Here is my problem because i dont know the lenght and the keywords. So I dont know how to get the information from the path.
kewords could look like this:
['files','important','folder1']

If the keywords are this, then the path should look like this.

```
   information = data["storage"]["files"]["important"]["folder1"]
```

This works but i dont know how to do it if the key words are diffrent.

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

```
{
  "storage":{
    "files":{
      "important":{
        "folder1":{"age":"25", "gender":"male"}
      }
    }
    "someotherdata":{"age":"5", "gender":"female"}
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data file.

Comment: You can try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71009209/how-to-create-an-automatic-mapping-of-possible-json-data-options-to-be-collected/71009454#71009454

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `key` in the `data.keys()`:

```
if some_key in data["storage"]["files"]["important"].keys():
    do_something
```

or use `try` block:

```
try:
    res = data["storage"]["files"]["important"][key]
except KeyError:
    ....
```

or use `get()` method:

```
res = data["storage"]["files"]["important"].get(key)
if not res:
    res = data["storage"]["files"]["important"].get(other_key)
```

To get all values in `data["storage"]["files"]["important"]` you can try:

```
res = {}
for v in data["storage"]["files"]["important"].values():
    res.update(**v)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'age': '25', 'gender': 'male'}
```

Comment: I know the the keys are existing, but my problem is that is dont know how to get the information because the are multipe keywords which i need in a row to get the data. data["storage"]["files"]["important"][key] doesnt work because files and important are keys too.

Comment: @FatCat You need to get all information from `important` block in case when there multi keys, correct?

Comment: Yes, there are multi keys with i get fron the get_keywords funtion. It just returns a List with the keys.