# Turn dictionary values into JSON paths

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have this dictionary/json file:

```
{ 
      'animal': {
            'cat': {
                'Persian': {}, 
                'British_Shorthair': {} 
            },
            'dog': {
                'Pug': {},
                'Pitbull': {}
            }
       },
      'vehicle': {
            'car': {
                'Mercedes': {},
                'BMW': {}
            }
       }
}
```

And I want turn this into a list of paths, meaning sth like this:

```
[ [animal, cat, persian], [animal, cat, british_shorthait], 
[animal, dog, pug], [animal, dog, pitbull], [vehicle, car, mercedes], 
[vehicle, car, bmw] ]
```

My file is much bigger than the example, but the structure is the same. They're all 3 levels, meaning all the paths are the same length.

Any ideas how to do this in just a few lines of code?
I used multiple for-loops to get a decent solution, but it's quite inconvenient

Comment: Something a bit similar here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71009209/how-to-create-an-automatic-mapping-of-possible-json-data-options-to-be-collected

Comment: _I used multiple for-loops to get a decent solution, but it's quite inconvenient_ -> Please [edit] your question and show us what you did

Comment: Nothing wrong with straightforward code that does the job?

Comment: The main reason I can imagine for doing it differently would be to handle varying numbers of levels, if you needed to do that, but they're all 3 here

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with using multiple for-loops? In this way, you could achieve the result in 'a few lines of code'.

```
my_dict = { 
  'animal': {
        'cat': {
            'Persian': {}, 
            'British_Shorthair': {} 
        },
        'dog': {
            'Pug': {},
            'Pitbull': {}
        }
   },
  'vehicle': {
        'car': {
            'Mercedes': {},
            'BMW': {}
        }
    }
}


my_list = []
for level1 in my_dict.keys():
  for level2 in my_dict[level1].keys():
    for level3 in my_dict[level1][level2].keys():
      my_list.append([level1, level2, level3])

print(my_list)
```

```
>>> 
[['animal', 'cat', 'Persian'], ['animal', 'cat', 'British_Shorthair'], ['animal', 'dog', 'Pug'], ['animal', 'dog', 'Pitbull'], ['vehicle', 'car', 'Mercedes'], ['vehicle', 'car', 'BMW']]
```

Or, using a list comprehension you could even do it in one line:

```
[[level1, level2, level3] for level1 in my_dict.keys() for level2 in my_dict[level1].keys() for level3 in my_dict[level1][level2].keys()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with structures with any number of levels (and it is short anyway).

```
def foo(_dict):
    if not _dict:
        return [[]]
    return [[k, *p] for k,v in _dict.items() for p in foo(v)]
```

Comment: If we're doing code golf, we can also write: `def foo(d): return [[k, *p] for k,v in d.items() for p in foo(v)] or [[]]`

Comment: Note that this answer and @Hiibb's answer give different results for an empty dictionary, which may be an issue

Answer (score 0):

There is already a convention for this called [JSON paths](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/internet-drafts/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base-05.html).

The following method will create a list of json paths from a dictionary.

```py
import collections

def get_paths(source):
    paths = []
    if isinstance(source, collections.abc.MutableMapping):
        for k, v in source.items():
            if k not in paths:
                paths.append(k)
            for x in get_paths(v):
                if k + '.' + x not in paths:
                    paths.append(k + '.' + x)
    elif isinstance(source, collections.abc.Sequence) and not isinstance(source, str):
        for x in source:
            for y in get_paths(x):
                if '[].' + y not in paths:
                    paths.append('[].' + y)
    return paths
```

The result of using the data above will be the following.

```
[
 'animal',
 'animal.cat',
 'animal.cat.Persian',
 'animal.cat.British_Shorthair',
 'animal.dog',
 'animal.dog.Pug',
 'animal.dog.Pitbull',
 'vehicle',
 'vehicle.car',
 'vehicle.car.Mercedes',
 'vehicle.car.BMW'
]
```