# List of paths to a nested Map structure

Tags: dart

I have a list of paths like the following:

```dart
[ "animal/cat/persian", "animal/cat/british_shorthait", 
"animal/dog/pug", "animal/dog/pitbull", "vehicle/car/mercedes", 
"vehicle/car/bmw"]
```

and I need to convert it into a nested structure (Map)

```dart
{ 
  'animal': {
        'cat': {
            'Persian': {}, 
            'British_Shorthair': {} 
        }
        'dog': {
            'Pug': {},
            'Pitbull': {}
        }
   }
  'vehicle': {
        'car': {
            'Mercedes': {},
            'BMW': {}
        }
}
```

The paths are of varying length and can be infinitely deep.
Any ideas on how to do this in a performant manner?
This is akin to a reverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71479690/turn-dictionary-values-into-paths/71480973?noredirect=1#comment126341789_71480973)

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize an empty `Map` for the results.
2. For each path in your list, split it into a list of keys.  Use the `Map` from step 1 as the initial `Map` for each path.
3. For each key, retrieve the nested `Map` for that key in the current `Map`, creating it if necessary.  Make the retrieved `Map` the current one.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var mapPaths = [
    "animal/cat/persian",
    "animal/cat/british_shorthair",
    "animal/dog/pug",
    "animal/dog/pitbull",
    "vehicle/car/mercedes",
    "vehicle/car/bmw",
  ];
  
  var mapRoot = <String, dynamic>{};
  for (var path in mapPaths) {
    var currentMap = mapRoot;
    for (var key in path.split('/')) {
      currentMap = currentMap[key] ??= <String, dynamic>{};
    }
  }

  // Pretty-print `mapRoot`.
  print(JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ').convert(mapRoot));
}
```